Samsung Galaxy a136u 5g frp locked no PC
I have a a136u 5g phone I forgot my pin code and no access to account associated I need help with frp bypass. Nothing is working. None of the exploits I see online work. In talkback instead of talking back it says stop. I really need I. This phone it's all I have tyia

The linked Q&A is what we have with the FRP bypass. If any doesn't work, then probably all of them have been patched, and there's no simple bypass anymore.
